# .pyx script with pyautogui works in spyder/cmd, but not from bat file

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-file, spyder, pyautogui

MY pyx scripts with pyautogui in spyder and cmd, but not as a bat file.

proba.pyx

```
import pyautogui as p
p.alert('Foo')
```

Spyder F9 works
CMD works:  E:\Anyagok\Programozas\Python\projekts\gyak>proba.pyx
BAT file:
@py.exe E:\Anyagok\Programozas\Python\projekts\gyak\proba.pyx %*

```
    c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe:  
 can't open file '<unprintable file name>': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Another example, urge.pyx

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui as py
urls=['http://animepill.com/anime/sword-art-online/episodes',
     'http://animepill.com/anime/shingeki-no-kyojin/episodes',
     'http://animepill.com/anime/one-punch-man/episodes',
     'http://animepill.com/anime/boku-no-hero-academia/episodes',
     'http://animepill.com/anime/overlord/episodes',
     ]

for url in urls:
    webbrowser.open(url)

py.alert("""Sword of Art: NoPMO, 0408 vasárnap: 2. rész
         Overlord: nyitás
         többi: urge
         VALSALVA vagy egyél közben...""",'urge')
```

E:\Anyagok\Programozas\Python\projekts\elo\mindennap>urge.pyx WORKS
Spyder works

But in bat it says:
@py.exe E:\Anyagok\Programozas\Python\projekts\elo\mindennap\urge.pyx %*

```
 [...]
import pyautogui as py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'.
```

The default program for opening pyx is this btw:
'e:\Download\PROGIK\Anaconda2\pythonw.exe'
I had to install Visual Studio Community Python environment, because pyx files didn't work in spyder due to the 'unable to find vcvarsall.bat' error. Now everything works in spyder and CMD, but scripts with pyautogui don't in bat.

Comment: Do you need to change `@py.exe` in your batch file to `@e:\Donwload\PROGIK\Anaconda2\pythonw.exe`?

Comment: Thanks @Eric this solved it!

Answer (score 1):

As @Eric has said:
had to change in the batch file @py.exe to @e:\Download\PROGIK\Anaconda2\pythonw.exe